# Is it possible implement this using TableUI

Tags: swift

I'm not a native speaker of English, but I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow.
and I am just started to make my iOS App.

This table has 3 rows and a column can be added.

Or, Table has 3 columns and a row can be added.

I imagine table like this.

Is it possible implement this using native swift TableUI?

Thank you for reading.

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Comment: There isn't anything called "TableUI" in Swift. This is also not something that would be easily handled by any built-in components on iOS. However, this doesn't mean that you can't code a custom component yourself to do this.

Comment: I see, now I am trying to add 3 table view. But I think I can add data to 3 table at the same time. but Is it possible to scroll 3 table at the same time?

Comment: Not with the built-in UITableView. I suppose you could try to render each cell as 3 columns, but I think you’d be better off crafting your own component.

Answer (score 2):

What you've drawn looks like a kind of spreadsheet layout. It doesn't correspond to anything built in to iOS, except for the basic fact that it's a drawing.

If the goal is to lay out elements in more or less the relationship that your drawn cells have, with multiple rows and columns, you could use a UICollectionView to formulate a kind of grid layout.